# Changing Style of WMS dynamically in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wms

I have a Leaflet WMS Layer

```
layer = new L.tileLayer.wms('https://{s}.url.com/wms?', {
    layers: 'Workspace:Layer',
    format: 'image/png',
    version: '1.3.0',
    transparent: true,
    styles: 'style1',
});
```

If I choose 'style2', it works as expected, but I want to change it dynamically with a select box.
I tried the following but it does not work:

```
<select id="styles">
    <option selected="selected" onselect="layer.styles='style1';">Style1</option>
    <option onselect="layer.styles='style2';">Style2</option>
</select>
```

I also tried with `layer.options.styles=''`

Comment: Does selecting the new style generate a new GetMap request?

Comment: probably not ...

Comment: WMS style is applied on the server, not in the client, though...

Comment: I know that ... But I can change the style with the GetMap request in the URL with "STYLE=[...]". So yes, there should be a new GetMap request when I change the Style, but how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution:

From [Leaflet reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#tilelayer-wms):

> **setParams**: Merges an object with the new parameters and re-requests tiles on the current screen (unless noRedraw was set to true).

So the following works:

```
<select id="styles" onchange="layer.setParams({styles: this.value});">
    <option selected="selected"  value="style1">Style 1</option>
    <option value="style2">Style 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this - finding it has just saved me a lot of time and hassle.

Comment: Can't find this method on Leaflet documentation. Is it deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to handle it in the logic part of your application, instead of HTML side. You could use

```
Util.setOptions(<your_layer>, {})
```

`Util` comes from leaflet library; <your_layer> it the layer (in your case a WMS layer) you want to update; `{}` is the object that contains the properties you want to change.